# how to Show one category posts in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Need to display 5 posts in one category and hide posts in other categories in index.php in wordpress from this code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

what's code to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `pre_get_posts` action hook

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_main_query() // Make sure we only target the main query
         && $q->is_home() // Targets the home page only
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        $q->set( 'cat', 1 ) ; // Set 1 to the correct ID of your category
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do query_post just before the loop

```
   query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'my-category-slug','posts_per_page'   => 5 ) );
```

If you want posts from more than one category then you can use
      query_posts('cat=8,4,3');
      8,4,3 are the id for the 3 categories

Comment: You must never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object which in turn breaks a lot of other stuff. It is also much slower as it reruns queries